# Checkout projects from https://android.googlesource.com

Tags: android, git, android-source

I'm using Windows 8, 64 bytes and trying to follow the explanation in http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html with no luck. I've notice that this explanation is better suite Linux users then Windows+Cygwin users so I decided to install git and use it.

My problem is that when I'm trying to perform "git clone [URL]" it always says "fatal: remote error: Git repository not found".

Strange thing, when I'm doing the following: 
    git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest it works and cloning the manifest.

I'm getting similar errors when I'm using "Download SVN"

I'm sure that there is an easier way to download/check out code from www.googlesource.com
 and would love to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use a Linux VM, because the Manuals are all for Linux (as you have seen).

Because you are on Windows i´d use:

[VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) (No VMWare Player because VirtualBox is more user friendly)

and

[Debian](http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable) (or another Linux like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)).

Be sure to check Network Bridge to your current network adaptor (e.g. Atheros Wlan-XX Chip..)

Good Luck !

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, i´d use ubuntu, too but if you want a headless system (much faster on some VM´s) my favourite is Debian.